# Gauss Map in the dual projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ X $ be a Fermat cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ i.e. $F = X_0^3 + X_1^3 \dots +X_n^3$ we denote the image of the Gauss map of $ X $ in the dual projective space $\check{\mathbb{P}^{n}}$ to be $ \check{X} $. Is $ \check{X} $ irreducible? What is the degree of $ \check{X} $?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The image of an irreducible variety is always irreducible.