# Gauss map in the projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to solve Exercise 6.5.3  (An Invitation to algebraic geometry, Karen E. Smith).
Let $V\subseteq$P$^2$ be the curve defined by the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$. Describe the Gauss map and find the defining equation.

Then the Gauss map is $[x:y:z]\rightarrow [x^2:y^2:z^2]$, but I have no idea how to find its defining equation. Can I find its degree?

Comment: [Seems to be a popular topic to ask about these days](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616290/gauss-map-in-the-dual-projective-space).

Answer (score 1):

Write $u=x^2$, $v=y^2$ and $w=z^3$.

On the curve we have that $x^3+y^3=-z^3$, so that $$
u^3+2x^3y^3+v^3 = (x^3+y^3)^2 = (-z^3)^2 = w^3.$$ This tells us that $$u^3+v^3-w^3=-2x^3y^3.$$ Squaring again we see that $$(u^3+v^3-w^3)^2=4u^3v^3.$$

This gives us an equation in the homogeneous coordinates $(u:v:w)$ that is satisfied by all the tangent lines to the curve we started with. This looks rather asymmetric, but can be rewritten as $$u^6+v^6+w^6=2u^3v^3+2u^3w^3+2v^3w^3.$$